# I need to pull a specific number from the last line of an MSI Afterburner log file in regex

Tags: regex

I know nothing about regex but I need to be able to select values from the last line of a log that prints like this:

```
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:27, 16.000              ,1392.000            ,4714.182            
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:28, 6.000               ,860.500             ,810.000             
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:29, 7.000               ,860.500             ,810.000             
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:30, 7.000               ,354.000             ,405.000
```

I need a regex that will grab the spot where the 354.000 (number between 100 and 9999) is in this instance, like this:

```
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:27, 16.000              ,1392.000            ,4714.182            
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:28, 6.000               ,860.500             ,810.000             
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:29, 7.000               ,860.500             ,810.000             
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:30, 7.000               ,**354**.000             ,405.000
```

As well as a regex that will grab the spot where the 405 is in this instance, like this:

```
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:27, 16.000              ,1392.000            ,4714.182            
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:28, 6.000               ,860.500             ,810.000             
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:29, 7.000               ,860.500             ,810.000             
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:30, 7.000               ,354.000             ,**405**.000
```

I'm using a program called CrystalControl2 to display information from my computer on an external LCD screen. The tool built into the program to grab information from text files or html pages requires a regex to pull results from the unfiltered source information.

To be more specific the log file adds a line to the text file with my GPU core clock and memory clock in the locations I highlighted once per second. I want to pull those updated values and display them in fields on the LCD screen via CrystalControl2. I'm trying to get these values without installing other software that is more easily accessible from CrystalControl2 to avoid both software conflicts as well as running a handful of different programs to reference all the information I want to display on my LCD

Like I said, these numbers can be either 3 or 4 digit numbers... is this at all possible?

Comment: Why regex?  Specifically what tool are you using and why?  Beware of [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm using a program called CrystalControl2 to display information from my computer on an external LCD screen.  The tool built into the program to grab information from text files or html pages requires a regex to pull results from the unfiltered source information.

Comment: To be more specific the log file adds a line to the text file with my GPU core clock and memory clock in the locations I highlighted once per second. I want to pull those updated values and display them in fields on the LCD screen via CrystalControl2. To avoid the XY problem here I'm trying to get these values without installing other software that is more easily accessible from CrystalControl2 to avoid both software conflicts as well as running a handful of different programs to reference all the information I want to display on my LCD screen.

Comment: OK, so to be able to do a regex, will need:  which columns, and what are we looking for.  So far you have indicated columns 3 and 4, numbers with a decimal point.  Is this accurate?

Comment: Oh, and I have soft spot spot for jarheads, but do us a favor and go look at the the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour)

Comment: I apologize, I'm very new to this (hence my reaching out for help), but I don't know to be honest. Wouldn't it be columns 4 and 5? I don't really know how the columns are determined, but I'm assuming it's the comma

Comment: Columns are determined in this case by the commas.  Need to be careful to only match what you are after.

Comment: Then yes, I need the last number in the 4th and 5th columns. And thank you for your assistance; I read the tour page and I wish I didn't have to go back and forth in comments, but I don't have enough reputation to request a chat.

Comment: Depending on how the that program handles it you won't be able to grab that information. Is there an option to just get the last line of a file? If you not, potentially, you could match every instance that matches the pattern and just matching the last line of a file isn't really what RegEx is for. Have a look at something like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com) to "design" the regular expression. It's probably going to be something like `(.*),(.*?),(.*?)$`.

Answer (score 0):

So evidently there is a serious lack of documentation for the CrystalControl2 regex format.  But from what I have gathered from looking at the *very* few examples I could find, they use grouping to extract the needed text.  Some have more groups than others and it was not clear to me why.  But here is a crack at a regex to match the numbers in the MSI Afterburner log.

```
\D+(\d+)\.[^,]*,[^0-9,]*(\d+)\.[^,]*$
```

#### How?

So let's break this apart.  We will work backwards from the end since we have an end of line anchor (`$`)

1. `$` - anchor to the end of the line.

   Although from the examples it appeared to me that this anchors to the end of file.
2. `[^,]*` - match zero or more of anything *but* commas
3. `\.` - match a dot (decimal point).

   The `\` is necessary because `.` is special in regex and means match anything.  The `\` makes it just a dot.
4. `(\d+)` - match one or more digits, and group them with the `()`.

   The group allows the match result to be extracted.
5. `,[^0-9,]*` - match a comma followed by zero or more non-digits or commas
6. `\.[^,]*` - find a dot followed by zero or more non-commas
7. `\D+(\d+)` - find one or more non-digits followed by one or more digits and group the digits

#### Testing:

Since I don't have access to the LCD or its SW, I used perl to test this like:

```
cat file1 | perl -lpe 's/\D+(\d+)\.[^,]*,[^0-9,]*(\d+)\.[^,]*$/:::: \1 xxx \2/'
```

#### Test Results:

```
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:27, 16.000:::: 1392 xxx 4714
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:28, 6.000:::: 860 xxx 810
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:29, 7.000:::: 860 xxx 810
80, 21-06-2017 20:42:30, 7.000:::: 354 xxx 405
```

So the regex found the last two numbers on the line as can be seen between the `:::` and `xxx`

#### Results Update from Comments

[image: Results]

Comment: It successfully pulled both the numbers I needed! Thank you!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4sm5oqumtqbkylj/Text.jpg

Comment: @JasonUpdegraff, you are very welcome.  However, on SU the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful. (Once you get 15 Rep)  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Well What have you tried ,

I would suggest to have a look at [NimbleText](http://nimbletext.com/) , Fairly easy to use

I am not fully understand your problem , but I have created a snippet here to help further.

http://nimbletext.com/Live/-176683481/

```
<% ($3 > 100 && $3 < 9999) ? $3 : '' %> | <% ($4 > 100 && $4 < 9999) ? $4 : '' %>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Answers need to be self containing, if anything happens to your link then your answer won't have any useful information. Please edit your post to include more information.